# Visual Studio AppCenter build fails with Bash exited with code '1'

Tags: rxjs, visual-studio-app-center

I have a react-native app that I'm trying to build with VS AppCenter and I have a hard time figuring out what the build error is.  Looking at the logs it appears to be on step `6 Generate Source Map`

Is the error an rxjs error `Property left of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["LVal"] but instead got "ConditionalExpression"` and is that what's causing the build to fail?  If so how come it runs and builds locally just fine?

```
##[section]Starting: Generate source map
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : This is an early preview. Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
Version      : 2.127.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/_temp/foo.sh
Found index.js for ReactNative index.
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/1/s/node_modules (33ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/1/s/node_modules (31ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
/Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/1/s/node_modules/rxjs/symbol/iterator.js: /Users/vsts/agent/2.134.2/work/1/s/node_modules/rxjs/symbol/iterator.js: Property left of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["LVal"] but instead got "ConditionalExpression"
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Generate source map
```

Googling it I found this potentially related bug https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6063 but most of the solutions seem to be to update to an outdated babel preset.

Here are my dependencies

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "^0.55.3",

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
```